# Tracing BST Pseudocode for Insertion

Tags: binary-search-trees, pseudocode

I'm having real trouble tracing some pseudocode for insetion into a Binary Search Tree. I need to understand this in order to be able to teach it, but I think there are flaws in the material.

For example,

`CALL FindInsertionPoint(NewDataItem, Index, Direction)`

is only meant to have one parameter according to the description in the question, and should return Index and Direction:

[image]

Doesn't this make the line before it in the code below:

`Index ← RootPointer`

redundant?

```
PROCEDURE AddToTree(BYVALUE NewDataItem : STRING)
// if no free node report an error
    IF FreePointer = -1
        THEN
            OUTPUT("No free space left")
        ELSE // add new data item to first node in the free list
            NewNodePointer ← FreePointer
            Tree[NewNodePointer].Data ← NewDataItem
            // adjust free pointer
            FreePointer ← Tree[FreePointer].LeftPointer
            // clear left pointer
            Tree[NewNodePointer].LeftPointer ← -1
            // is tree currently empty ?
            IF RootPointer = -1 
                THEN // make new node the root node
                    RootPointer ← NewNodePointer
                ELSE // find position where new node is to be added
                    Index ← RootPointer
                    CALL FindInsertionPoint(NewDataItem, Index, Direction)
                    IF Direction = "Left"
                        THEN // add new node on left
                            Tree[Index].LeftPointer ← NewNodePointer
                        ELSE // add new node on right
                            Tree[Index].RightPointer ← NewNodePointer 
                    ENDIF
            ENDIF
    ENDIF
ENDPROCEDURE
```

I've tried tracing the algorithm for the data from the question I get stuck quite early on because I can't tell what value for Index should be returned from FindInsertionPoint().

The input sequence is: Dublin, London, Berlin, Paris, Madrid, Copenhagen, Athens.

When all is done, the result should look like this:

[image]

I need help working out what is due to my own lack of understanding and what is due to problems with the material. It would be great to see a correct trace table for the algorithm using the data given.

In partcular, how can I work out the return values for the `FindInsertionPoint()` function?

Thanks in advance.

Below is an image of the algorithm given in the solutions (same as pseudocode above).

[image]

Comment: You say "the description in the question".  What question?  Please reference the source of all copied material (including code or images/screenshots).

Comment: Cambridge International Examinations A Level past paper 2017.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to put it in your post, not in the comments.  The comments exist to help you improve your question.  Thank you!